# Guarding against stack overflows in APM

Tags: c#, asynchronous, threadpool, stack-overflow

The Good Book says, that when implementing the asynchronous programming model, there is always a possibility of the callback to be called synchronously many times in a row causing stack overflow. The problem is that I can't even come close to reproducing this situation. Even the program below, which sends itself a large message over tcp, and then reads it one byte at a time, once in a few dozen of runs falls into recursion only several levels deep.

So, is this really a problem? Or is it merely scaremongering, that makes you add two extra methods to an already bulky pattern? And if it really is, why not just put BeginMethod in the queue for the thread pool instead of calling it directly when the callback is executed on the same thread?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

class Program {
    static byte[] buff = new byte[1];
    static int cntr = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 11111);
        listener.Start();
        new Action(() => {
            byte[] message = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
            var client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 11111);
            using (var s = client.GetStream()) s.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
        }).BeginInvoke(null, null);
        var stream = listener.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream();
        stream.BeginRead(buff, 0, buff.Length, callback, stream);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void callback(IAsyncResult iar) {
        if (iar.CompletedSynchronously) Console.Write(cntr++ +" "); else cntr=0;
        var stream = iar.AsyncState as NetworkStream;
        if (stream.EndRead(iar) > 0) {
            stream.BeginRead(buff, 0, buff.Length, callback, stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow may occur if you put too many objects in the stack of the one individual thread. Async `new Action(..).BeginInvoke()` or in fact any delegate `BeginInvoke`  uses threads available [from thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3556634/706456), so any new async call would either:

- Take a new thread from a pool if available (use it and return back to the pool) 
  or
- Wait for a thread to be returned or additionally created

So if you want to reproduce a SO exception, make sure you load only one thread. BTW, `byte[] message` is stored in a managed heap.

Comment: Async call can finish it's job synchronously and don't use the thread pool at all, but only if it can finish its task very quickly. Reading one byte from a socket is the smallest real life task I could come up with.