# Delegate.BeginInvoke Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I Know that `Delegate.BeginInvoke()` initiates the asynchronous call on a separate thread taken from the `ThreadPool`. But i still have a confusion whether that thread must be always different from caller thread or both method can be on the same thread.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556634/does-funct-begininvoke-use-the-threadpool

Comment: it is never the caller's thread.  It can't be, the caller keeps motoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called asynchronously (so it must be on a different thread). You can execute something in between and possibly wait for the asynchronous operation to finish with EndInvoke.